Deleted Items from Shared Mailbox Still Moving to users Deleted Items
I need to prefix this by stating that I have seen the previous question about this already and this was for much earlier versions of Outlook.
Outlook is running version 2407
I have carried out the DelegateWastebasket registry fix in the correct location and the user is still experiencing the issue of deleted items from the shared mailbox are ending up in their deleted items and not the shared mailboxes.
Is there any other fixes for this issue in Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise running Windows 11 if the registry change seems to take no effect at all?
For Reference the DelegateWasteBasket reg fix is adding a DWORD named "DelegateWastebasketStyle" with a value of 4 in the below registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\General
I have tried asking ChatGPT for any other possible fixes and it suggests a workaround of manually moving the items to the correct folder.

Will manually deleted messages still appear in a shared mailbox?

@Soki There is an age old bug in Outlook where deleted items from a shared mailbox are moved to the deleted items within the users mailbox and not the deleted items of the shared mailbox meaning these emails cannot be viewed by other users that have access to the shared mailbox.. The reg fix is supposed to force them to go to the deleted items of the shared mailbox instead.
